# How can I archive that only one button can be selected in a ListView widget?

Tags: flutter

I created a horizontal ListView with OutlinedButtons and I want to archive that only one button can be selected at the time for filter purposes. At the moment I can select as many I want. I would appreciate if someone could help me here.

```
class _CategoriesListViewState extends State<CategoriesListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: widget.categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CreateCategoryButton(
            category: widget.categories[index],
            index: index,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _CreateCategoryButtonState extends State<CreateCategoryButton> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor:
            isSelected ? Constants.backGroudColor : Colors.transparent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 0.7,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.onPressed;

        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
        });
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          widget.category,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Constants.textAndButtomColor,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.montserratAlternates().fontFamily),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want to keep track of the selected category. From your code, it seems your category is a string.

You could create a variable to hold the selected category and pass to your custom button, as shown below.

```
class _CategoriesListViewState extends State<CategoriesListView> {
  String? _selectedCategory;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: widget.categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CreateCategoryButton(
            category: widget.categories[index],
            selectedCategory: _selectedCategory,
            onPressed: () {
             setState((){
              _selectedCategory = widget.categories[index];
             });
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You should note that I have removed index from the `CreateCategoryButton` as it doesn't appear to be in use according to your code.

Add a selectedCategory parameter to your CreateCategoryButton. You should have something similar to the following:

```
class CreateCategoryButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateCategoryButton({Key? key, this.selectedCategory})
      : super(key: key);

  final String? selectedCategory;

  @override
  State<CreateCategoryButton> createState() => _CreateCategoryButtonState();
}
```

You should also edit the button state to match the below:

```
class _CreateCategoryButtonState extends State<CreateCategoryButton> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSelected = widget.category == widget.selectedCategory;
    return OutlinedButton(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor:
            isSelected ? Constants.backGroudColor : Colors.transparent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 0.7,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: widget.onPressed,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          widget.category,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Constants.textAndButtomColor,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.montserratAlternates().fontFamily),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The basic idea is to create a selectedCategory variable and compare against the button category hence why we did:  `widget.category == widget.selectedCategory`.